# Extract shape from image by color

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to make a logo in Adobe Illustrator. On the logo I want to put the outline of a certain lake on it. I took a screenshot from google maps of the lake. How would I go about extracting this shape? Is there a function that will take advantage of the fact that the lake is all one color?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried live trace? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvnd3m5aYBs

Comment: Live trace works best with the highest resolution you can get for the image. Unless the lake outline is super-complex, you may find the pen tool gives you a better result, especially for a logo, where simpler is better.

Comment: Flag the question as answered, if you would, so Chris gets the credit for it.